# Memory leak detection on Mac OS

Tags: c, memory-leaks, lldb

I’m trying to debug a C code and unfortunately I can’t use valgrind since I have Mavericks installed.

I’m using `lldb` but am not sure what command to run to check for memory leaks.

Comment: You would likely use [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), and in particular the [memory profiling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW1) sensors therein. Assuming you have Xcode installed with all its tools, of course.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else works, you might try using [dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com/) library, which has been ported to OS X and is pretty good at finding reasonably complex memory allocation problems.